# upper_bound in C++

Tags: c++, math, upperbound

`arr[]= {1,3,3,7,4,4}`
`upper_bound(arr+3,arr+6,3,greater<int>())-arr` should return 5 right (It should point to last 4 whose index is 5 because it is the first greater element after 3 ) ? But it is returning 6.What am I missing here?

Comment: @NathanOliver The range is `arr+3,arr+6`. It is `7, 4, 4` and this is sorted.

Comment: check the parameters of upper_bound(), I am passing [arr+3 ,arr+6)

Comment: @MikeCAT Dang off by one errors ;)

Comment: "greater" has its meaning flipped since it really means "opposite direction of the predicate", and is not the default of `less`

Comment: @MikeCAT sorted non-decreasing order...

Comment: Look at the "Second implementation" source code at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound .  If necessary, paste that into your file and call it instead, and you can follow it in the debugger.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: the opposite of `<` is `>=`, not `>`.  You need `std::greater_equal`

Comment: No, it doesn't mean `[arr+6,arr+3)` like a reverse iterator.  I was thinking that "greater" in your quote is actually (!comp(left,right)) which is the opposite of `comp` which is `greater<>`.  It ran to the End before finding a match.

Comment: @JDługosz I don't understand :(

Comment: Your `upper_bound` currently returns `std::end(arr)` (or rather `arr + 6`) which means it didn't find a matching element.

Comment: @TedLyngmo but the first number that is greater than 3 is 4 whose index is 5 .

Comment: There is no number *less than* 3 in that sequence. that `upper_bound` looks for the first `elem` where `comp(elem, 3)` is false, and none are

Comment: If you still don't understand, trace through the simple implementation I noted earlier.  Also, if "greater" is still messing you up, remove the predicate argument and negate all the test values and look at it again.